# Story Identification: Novel in which aliens drain sun's energy

Tags: story-identification, books, novel

I read this book in my school's library and that was a long time ago (long enough ago that I don't remember). I will give my best to reproduce the important parts of it. Few scientists, while working on something in Antarctica observe that the sun goes dark for a very minute fraction of a second. One of the scientists recalls that this happened before and they investigate on that. Later they observe through some telescopic images that an alien space ship was draining energy from sun which caused that small moment of darkness.They then go near the sun and try to stop the aliens and save the human race. I also remember the last scene. The scientist's daughter watches the beautiful sun rising the next morning.

It is not a juvenile book. I don't wholly remember the story. coming to less important parts, the scientist, our hero will have some marriage issues. His wife also ends up on the same mission. They both will have a large age gap I think but am not sure.

Comment: When was a long time ago? 50 years ago? Was it an "adult" or a "juvenile" book? Please mention any **unimportant** parts that you can remember, they can be helpful in identifying the story, by distinguishing it from all the other stories about alien sun-stealers.

Comment: For example, Wollheim's *The Secret of the Ninth Planet*--the subject of [this old question](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/67053/older-novel-boy-can-operate-alien-machines-saves-the-planet)--was about alien sun stealers. But the final showdown with the alien is not near the sun, it's in the outer solar system, out around Pluto and Neptune.

Comment: @user14111 long enough to forget the title lets say. It is not a juvenile book. I don't wholly remember the story. coming to less important parts, the scientist, our hero will have some marriage issues. His wife also ends up on the same mission. They both will have a large age gap I think but am not sure.

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: In case the OP comes back: If it was in a school library, you can easily be more specific than "long enough ago to forget" - if you left school in 1973, it must have been before then; if you're still at school, it can't be more than about 15 years ago. It's probably really obvious to you which applies, but we have no way of knowing. (Meanwhile, it's now 7 years longer ago...)

Answer (score -2):

The third book in Dennis Feltham Jones' "Colossus Trilogy", [Colossus and the Crab](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Colossus_and_the_Crab) had aliens from Mars that were stealing the Earth's oxygen. It may not the same book (depends upon how well the OP remembered the details), but that is immediately what came to mind when I read the question.

Comment: It doesn't seem like a terribly good match.