# Aliens exchange their dying sun for ours. Humans steal their ship and seek revenge

Tags: story-identification, novel, soft-sci-fi

I'm looking for a book about aliens exchanging our sun with their dying sun (or some other sun). Humans must retreat underground to survive. Years later, aliens make contact and humans ambush them to steal their spacecraft so that they can take revenge. The aliens do not make contact on Earth, they make contact on the Moon. Their reason for contact was to help the humans, but I think they did not feel they did anything wrong.

Comment: Possible dupe of https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/84548/story-identification-novel-in-which-aliens-drain-suns-energy - But not answered.

Comment: How was the Sun exchanged for another star? Some kind of hyperdimensional device? It seems basically unlikely as it would be easier to simply move the aliens' planet to the Sun.

Comment: John Rennie, huh?? it is a book.

Comment: @RichardSundal Well yes, but even in fiction we expect characters to behave in ways that make some sense and it seems silly for aliens to move an entire star when they could just move a planet. Though I have to concede I have read many SF books that make no sense at all :-) Anyhow, do you remember how the alien's star was swapped for the Sun?